# How to enter array type value for angular schematics

Tags: json, angular-schematics

I'm learning Angular Schematics and have some problems regarding **array type input**.

When I am prompted to enter a value and press enter the value disappears. What is the correct way of entering an array value?

[image]

My **schema.json** is the following:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema",
    "id": "HelloWorldSchematics",
    "title": "Hello World Options Schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "listName": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "The name of the list.",
        "$default": {
          "$source": "argv",
          "index": 0
        },
        "x-prompt": "What's the name of list"
      },
      "colNames": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "description": "The name of the columns.",
        "x-prompt": "What's the name of columns"
      }
    },
    "required": [
        "listName",
        "colNames"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to enter a value **using the flag**. Following your example, you can enter values like this:

```
schematics ./collection.json:HelloWorld --listName User --colNames={id,firstName}
```

Notice that **there is no space between the elements of the array**.

The following **WOULD NOT WORK**:

```
schematics ./collection.json:HelloWorld --listName User --colNames={id, firstName}
```